# Is it better to return an empty (Entity) List or null?

Tags: list, jpa, null, return, entity

A method is returning a list of persons, which might be empty.

**Is it better to return an *empty list* or just *null*?**

Some might find this as an opinion question, but I want to know what is the best strategy for a new application?

```
public List<PersonEntity> findByName(List<String> names) {
    List<PersonEntity> list = new ArrayList<PersonEntity>();
    ...JPA-stuff getting that list
    return list;
}
```

Returning null. Is a null easier to handle further on?

```
public List<PersonEntity> findByName(List<String> names) {
    List<PersonEntity> list = null;
    ...JPA-stuff getting that list
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this may in turn be an opinion question, but I like returning the empty set and avoid having to handle null if it can be.

It all depends on what you do with this list, but lets say once you get the list back you need to iterate through it.

If its the empty set, you try to iterate, it doesn't see anything in the list, your okay.

```
 result = findByName(names);
 //...safe to loop through result
```

If its null, you try to iterate, you get an exception, and therefore need to check null first and add special handling.

```
result = findByName(names);
if (result != null)
{
    //...handle stuff (now it is safe to loop through result)
}
else
{
    //..special handling if needed
}
```

All in all, it depends what you are doing with the data, and if you can get away with not checking for empty set such as in my first example.

Comment: What would be the best strategy for a new application. Your personal opinion would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I personally usually go for returning null. When first creating the function I may not be fully aware of all the cases that it will be used, and I feel it beneficial to use null so that I can have the special handling if needed. Technically, you can reach the same outcome sending the empty set, but I feel its a cleaner and possibly more clear result with null.
I hope this helps. :)